# How to create a link to "End-to-end transaction details" using a Kusto Query

Tags: azure-application-insights

It is possible to create a link to 'End-to-end transaction details' for all exceptions returned using a Kusto query, such as

```
exceptions
 | where timestamp >= ago(1d)
 |  project  ['Work Item Type'] = 'Bug', Link = 'required End-to-end
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `link` or `related operator` in Kusto query, so you cannot create a link url.

And one more thing, Even if there was a `link` operator, how do you know the `End to end transaction url` for each exception?

Please let me know if you have more questions.